# Need advice on architecture of a Discord bot

Tags: mongodb, go, discord, architecture

### What is discord Role?

A role is a group created by server admins. The role has permissions, a hierarchy, and a name. What's essential in this case is that players can refer to multiple players at once ("ping" them) by referring to their role like this `@RoleName.`

## Context

I'm developing a bot that issues temporary roles to users. Users take Roles so that others can ping them. A Role is given for the duration user's desires. The bot is being written in `Go.` The whole app primarily consists of handlers of both Mongo events and commands that users type to the bot.

Each time user takes a role by typing a command to the bot, the Discord id of that user is stored inside the Mongo database with expiration time. Once a time stored within the document is reached, the document is deleted by Mongo (TTL index is used for this). Then via handling Mongo events, the bot handles deletion by taking away roles from users. (Also, the user may remove his role preemptively. In this case, the role is being taken away and the corresponding record from the database.)

## Question

When a user decides to remove his role, the Mongo deletion event handler is fired despite the user's record already being deleted inside the user command handler. So, I thought it was possible to control the bot exclusively inside Mongo's event handlers. Instead of giving and removing roles inside handlers corresponding to commands users gave, I can do so inside Mongo events. For example, to take away a role from the user, I need to remove his record from the database inside the command handler. Then role will be taken away automatically inside the corresponding Mongo event handler.

My experience does not let me foresee how this would affect future bot development, so I'm asking you for advice on this. Would this be a good idea? If not, what would be an excellent way to deal with Mongo handlers being fired in such cases as one above?

I suck at writing, so don't be shy to ask for clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the database is the authority on which users have which roles, your bot application serves as the bridge to keep Discord up to date with that authority.

Suppose you process role updates only on database events. In that case, this means your bridge application must be running and properly connected to both services without any error occurring at the time of every expiration. Otherwise, the state will fall out of sync. For correctness, it's best to design with the assumption that any or all of the three services could go offline at any time.

To keep your experience responsive and consistent, you should update the roles quickly and in as many places as is necessary to ensure eventual consistency. This may result in redundant updates, so check if the update is already applied and skip it if necessary.

Here's an example of update cases:

- On bot application startup: Update all users
- On database event: Update user
- On user command: Update user (optional, but may provide faster user feedback if DB events are delayed)
- On user joining server: Update user
- On periodic/background task: Update all users (optional, in case other updates fail or roles are modified by external sources)

Comment: Thank you. I've got a side question. 
"...design with the assumption that any or all of the three services could go offline at any time"
Suppose something broke. I've read about error handling in Go, that if state is irrecoverable (state of database does not reflect state of Discord server) the program should crash. Is that correct?

Comment: If the state is irrecoverable, then it goes without saying that you must not must not execute any subsequent code that requires the correct state. That doesn't mean you need to crash the whole program though. Crashing the program may not help, as you're dealing with Discord which you have no control over. For example, if the program tries to remove a role and encounters an error, you could crash the program, but the user will still have the wrong role.

Comment: It really depends on the application but most likely you want some combination of auto-retry on soft errors, logging on hard errors, and recovery paths when errors do not allow the program to continue (e.g., cancel the current command, tell the user there was an error).

Comment: "cancel the current command, tell the user there was an error". I probably have something like this implemented already. Suppose, user commands bot to give him a role. For that we need to give user a role and add a record to the database. If failure occurs at giving user a role I and return error to user and do nothing since state is not broken. If it occurs during adding record to db I take away role and return error. If I can't take away role I crash the program. Logging is done in all cases as well. Is that what you mean? Also, I'll implement retries as you said.

Comment: Seems to make sense. Perhaps more elegant than crashing is setting an error state per user, this disallowing the user to take actions affected by their error until it is resolved.